# Java Crypto: CFB and PCBC (not API based)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am currently working on finishing up a school project based on pretty standard cryptography principles. While I have the majority of what I need functioning correctly, I have run into an issue when manually implementing CFB and PCBC block ciphers. My source code is written in Java, and I believe the issue may involve something happening that I am not accounting for when doing the encryption operations or byte operations. For both ciphers the encryption used is 3DES, and I have tested that separately and it functions as I expect it to. Currently I am only looking to solve a simple case in which a string such as "testtest" (i.e. 16bytes) is correctly encrypted/decrypted. For cases of <=8 bytes the code functions as expected (whether by luck or not haha).  My code for the core functions  to this point is:

```
// for now encrypting at byte block level
protected String decrypt3DES_PCBC(byte[] input) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Length of input @derypt: " + input.length);
    Block[] output = new Block[input.length];
    int idxA = 0, idxB = 16;
    // P1
    block.setBlock(XOR(tripleDES.get3DESDecryption(Arrays.copyOfRange(
            input, idxA, idxB)), IV));
    output[0] = block;
    System.out.println("decrypt length: " + output[0].getBlock().length);
    System.out.println("Initial decoded block: "
            + new String(output[0].getBlock(), "UTF-16BE"));

    // P2
    block.setBlock(XOR(tripleDES.get3DESDecryption(Arrays.copyOfRange(
            input, idxA + 16, idxB + 16)), Arrays.copyOfRange(input, idxA,
            idxB), output[0].getBlock()));
    output[1] = block;
    System.out.println("decrypt length: " + output[1].getBlock().length);
    System.out.println("Next decoded block: "
            + new String(output[1].getBlock(), "UTF-16BE"));

    return null;
}

private byte[] XOR(byte[] pt, byte[] cText) {
    byte[] output = new byte[pt.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = (byte) (cText[i] ^ pt[i]);
    }
    return output;
}

private byte[] XOR(byte[] pt_0, byte[] pt_1, byte[] ct) {
    byte[] output = new byte[pt_0.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = (byte) (pt_0[i] ^ pt_1[i] ^ ct[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: `block`, `Block`, ... it looks like you left off all the important code.

Comment: Block is simply a storage unit for size 8 byte[]. I guess I was not too clear with the exact issue. For inputs of <=8 bytes (such as the word "test" or "a"), the encryption/decryption functions correctly, so once I decrypt I receive back the entered word ("test"). However, when extended past 8 bytes of info ("test1" for example), the decryption fails and I just receive garbage data.

Comment: just for reference: PCBC and CFB are both block cipher modes of operations, not block ciphers themselves.  They enable block ciphers like 3DES to operate on an input larger than its block size.

Answer (score 0):

You are jumping too far ahead in your cipher text for the second block.

TripleDES has a block size of 64 bits, which translates to 8 bytes. Your code seems to assume that the block size is 16 bytes, e.g. 128 bits.

I'm guessing the decryption algorithm implementation only takes the first 8 bytes in the arrays you pass it, so it manages to decrypt the first block (bytes 0-7) successfully (as you've indicated).  It then skips to index + 16, which will skip over the bytes from 8-15.

try changing the initial assignment to idxB to 8, and then change your second setBlock call to something like this:

```
 // P2
block.setBlock(XOR(tripleDES.get3DESDecryption(Arrays.copyOfRange(
        input, idxA + 8, idxB + 8)), Arrays.copyOfRange(input, idxA,
        idxB), output[0].getBlock()));
```

and I bet things will start working.